# refresh html table with onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm trying to refresh my table with onclick button, but nothing really comes out. Can't figure out what I do wrong here. Any ideas?

```
<div id="mytable">   
        <table>
             <tr>
                <td>{{ random_number }}</td>
                <td>{{ random_number }}</td>
                <td>{{ random_number }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
    </div>
    <script>
    function Reload()   {
        document.getElementById('mytable').innerHTML;
    }
    </script>
    <button onclick="Reload()">Refresh table</button>
```

Comment: Refresh from what? Are you receiving new data from somewhere?

Comment: Nothing comes out because your function doesn't do anything. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: `document.getElementById('mytable').innerHTML` do nothing

Comment: This could only work if your random number was dynamic, i.e. was created by a function, rather than user inputted.  At the moment it just says "random_number".

Comment: As you have it, clicking the table just takes all the data from the table, then stores it temporarily, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear What you are trying to refresh, But assuming you are trying to generate and refresh random numbers in the table, yu can try this:-

JS

```
 function Reload()   {

     document.getElementById('td1').innerHTML=GenRand();
     document.getElementById('td2').innerHTML=GenRand();
     document.getElementById('td3').innerHTML=GenRand();
    }
  function GenRand(){
     return Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);//generates random number between 1 and 10 , you can edit values to generate any range.
    }
```

HTML:-

```
<div >   
    <table  border="1">
         <tr >
           <td id="td1">1</td>
           <td id="td2">2</td>
           <td id="td3">3</td>
          </tr>
     </table> 
 </div>
 <button onclick="Reload()">Refresh table</button>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2W4ka/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a server-side framework (I think {{ random_number }} tag is used by a template/views systems) you must to get data from server.

You can use AJAX to get data or you can refresh all the page.